# Finding sequences of chars in a char iterator

Tags: rust, char

I am using Rust and wish to search a .chars() iterator. If I wanted to find a single char, then I could use something like:

```
fn main() {
    let mystring = "StackOverlflow";
    let theletterv = mystring.chars().position(|c| c == 'v');
    match theletterv {
        None => {println!("Not Found")}
        Some(i) => {println!("{:?}", i)}
    }
}
```

However, I wish to search for a sequence of chars. If I used a regular string, I could just use the .find() method, however this would only return a byte offset and I might have non-ascii characters.

Is there anything in the standard library that would allow me search for a Vec of chars, say ['v','e','r'] ?

Comment: I'd suggest using [`Itertools::tuple_windows`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows) as long as your sequence of chars is a set length. Otherwise, you'll probably have to create it yourself.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can't use `find` because that returns a byte index instead of a char index? It would probably be easier and faster to just get the byte index and count the chars up to it.

Comment: Wanting the char index also sounds like you may not understand exactly how chars work. For instance, an single accented "character" on the screen can be made up of multiple `char`s. You may really want to count "grapheme clusters" with something like [`UnicodeSegmentation::graphemes`](https://docs.rs/unicode-segmentation/latest/unicode_segmentation/trait.UnicodeSegmentation.html#tymethod.graphemes)

Answer (score 0):

> If I used a regular string, I could just use the .find() method, however this would only return a byte offset and I might have non-ascii characters.

Why is this a problem? The byte index is guaranteed to point at a valid code point:

```rust
let s = " Hello  World!";

let idx = s.find("").expect("Sequence not found");
let mut chars = s[idx..].chars();

assert_eq!(chars.next(), Some(''));
assert_eq!(chars.next(), Some(''));
assert_eq!(chars.next(), Some(' '));
```

However, if you more generally want to find a subsequence of consecutive elements in an iterator, the solution is to use a "windows" iterator. There are a few ways to do this:

- Use the [one in `itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows)
- Write your own, based on const generics. An example implementation I wrote last year is [here](https://github.com/Lucretiel/advent2021/blob/main/src/library.rs#L17-L92).